# How to make the first button in flexbox the same size as the second

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to make the first button the same size as the second? Regardless of the content in which the button is located. P.S. fixed width for the button is not suitable

```css
    .box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: max-content;
}
.box button{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 
<div class="box">
    <div class="one">
        <h2>long header</h2>
        <button>Abcde</button>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
        <h2>head</h2>
        <button>Abcde12321</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set the width of the buttons to the same value...?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the width of buttons to be as as same biggest button:
set the parent width to : `max-content`, and the childs to `width: 100%;`

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: max-content;
}
.box button{
  width: 100%;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/OJNwGVb?editors=1000)

Also you can set their width (or parent's width) to a fixed value like [this](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/GRZBLqq?editors=1000).

Ps: you can also use flex instead.

Comment: Thanks, this is suitable as a solution to the question I asked. But what if in each div I also have a heads or smth of different width? But I still need to achieve the preservation of the widths between buttons, regardless of other content.
P.S. fixed width does not fit

Comment: I changed my question for clarity

Comment: @МишаАнацкий it's not possible using css. the usual way to make it work is using a fixed width and truncating the content (google : 'truncate css text'). or using different heights: https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/poyZmGJ?editors=1000 . if you really want, you can use javascript to calculate the max content width of buttons, and set all buttons width to that. (there is also another workaround: changing the hirerachy, so that all buttons has a parent, and all heading has another parent. (separate headings and buttons.))